# Test callback using in a route with supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul

I started to `istanbul` as a test coverage tool with mocha and one of the great things is that it shows you the paths (branches) you have tested in your test code logic.

There is a path that can only be taken if a error occurs on the database.

[Screenshot of the part I am interested in testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS0WB.png)

The [I] indicates the the first `if` was not tested.
The problem is that it uses a callback `function(err, data)` and the error is passed to this callback through a the `mongoose` model method `find()`, and because of that I don't have the flow control of this part of the code.

In this specific case I using `supertest` which is a module to test routes in `node.js` and it make requests to a route that calls a `mongoose` model method `find()`.

What would be the best option to test this path? Create a stub to simulate the method? Or just remove the if?

**EDIT:** I noticed that I was using an anonymous function as a callback `(err, data)` and doing so I can't test it since it's not exposed to the outer scope. One approach I had in mind was to create a function:

```
handleDbFetchingResponse(res) {
    return function(err, data) {
        let response = {};
        if (err) {
            response = {error: true, message: 'Error fetching data'};
        } else {
            response = {error: false, message: data};
        }
        res.json(response);
    }
}
```

Now I can expose the function and test it, I create another problem though. Since the other express routes have another logic when fetching data from the database I will have to create a handler function for each one of them. Maybe there is a way to create a handlerBuilder function that returns a new handler passing different arguments to deal with specific cases.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it is what you're looking for, but have a look at Sinon.JS: http://sinonjs.org/.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp I tried `sinon`, but I don't know yet how it can tap into the `(err, data)` callback and throw an error. Maybe naming the callback and declaring it outside could work, don't know how though.